# Modify the values obtained through group_concat() in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I have the following [table a]

```
id     result

1       a
1       b
1       b
1       c
2       e
2       e
2       e
2       f
```

I'm getting the following  after doing a group_concat

```
select id , Group_Concat(result)  from [table a]
group by id

id     result

1      a,b,b,c
2      e,e,e,f
```

**BUT i want to display the no of times a value occurs before the value in the result set to avoid redundancy like the following**

```
  id     result

  1      a,2 b,c
  2      3 e,f
```

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by ID and result first to get the count. Then group by ID to build your strings.

```
select 
  id, 
  group_concat(case when cnt = 1 then result else concat(cnt, ' ', result) end) as results
from 
(
  select id, result, count(*) 
  from mytable 
  group by id, result
) t
group by id;
```